# How can you assign a value to the pointer 'this' in C++

Tags: c++, this

In a function, how to you assign `this` a new value?

Comment: The proper question, I suppose, would be 'why would you ever want to do that'?

Comment: This might be insightful, but the answer I was going to comment on was deleted: If it were `const`, then you could simply `const_cast` it back to something modifiable. The result would be undefined behavior, but it wouldn't be a syntax error. Applying `const_cast` to `this` OTOH will not compile in a well-behaved compiler.

Comment: Sounds like the [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can't.

#### 9.3.2 The this pointer [class.this]

> 1 In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword **`this` is a [prvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3601602/673730) expression** whose value
>   is the address of the object for which the function is called. [...] (emphasis & link mine)

You can modify the object `this` points to, which is `*this`. For example:

```
struct X
{
   int x;
   void foo()
   {
     this->x =3;
   }
};
```

The method modifies the object itself, but something like `this = new X` is illegal.

Comment: +1:  There is a nearly identical passage in the C++03 Standard.  Except of "prvalue" it says "non-lvalue"

Answer (score 48):

You can assign the object `this` points at:

```
*this = XY;
```

But you can't assign the direct value of `this`:

```
this = &XY;   // Error: Expression is not assignable
```

Comment: +1 for `*this = XY`, which gives the actual answer for one interpretation of the question (didn't seem to be the OP's interpretation, but was my interpretation).

Answer (score 21):

Long ago, before the first C++ standard has been published, some compiler implementations allowed you to write the following code inside a constructor:

```
this = malloc(sizeof(MyClass)); // <<== No longer allowed
```

The technique served as the only way to control allocation of class of objects. This practice has been prohibited by the standard, because overloading of the `operator new` has solved the problem that used to be tackled by assignments to `this`.

Comment: Weird thing is, Objective C does something similar :O

Comment: Also placement new: `delete this; new(this) MyClass();`

Answer (score 3):

You can't. If you feel the need to do this perhaps you should be writing a static method taking a class pointer as it's first parameter.

Comment: However, it should be a reference (or a pointer) to a class pointer in order to be modifiable.

Comment: It would be modifyable locally, even as a straight pointer. I was thinking of the situation where you have some recursive data structure, and you want to call a recursive or iterative routine, The initial pointer you pass to the routine is `this` but afterwards it recurses or iterates with different values for the pointer. But it seems I was completely wide of the mark. The OP has a more basic misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign value to `this` pointer. If you try to assign the value to the `this` somthing like `this = &a` it would result in illegal expression

Comment: I am writing a function that supposedly must modify this.  Are you saying that is not possible?

Comment: @AstraMeyers Completely impossible. Probably you misunderstood and are supposed to modify what `this` points to.

Comment: @AstraMeyers Why should your function modify `this` value - and not the properties of the object which it refers to?

Comment: You probably want to mody the state of 'this' instead of trying to modify where 'this' points to

Answer (score 0):

You can not.
"this" is a hidden argument to every member function of a class and its type for an object of Class X is X* const. This clearly means that you can not assign a new vale to "this" as it is defined as a const. You can however modify the value pointed to by this. Refer http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/this-pointer-in-c/ for more details.