# Javascript - Reassignment of class instance from its own method

Tags: javascript

is it possible to clone idiomatically a javascript class instance from within of its own method? Others languages like Java allow me to overwrite/clone the current instance by either construct overload or `this` overwrite. Javascript does not seems to like it, and throws the error `SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`. THere is an example below for this verbose explanation.

```js
class Car {
  constructor(name, year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;
  }

  renew() {
    this = new Car('Ferrari', 2021);
    return this
  }
}

car = new Car('Ford', 206)
car.renew()
```

Comment: You seem to be confused, you definitely can't do this in Java

Comment: "*other languages like Java allow me to overwrite/clone the current instance by either construct overload or this overwrite.*" - [no, they don't either](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7979623/1048572)

Comment: Maybe it was only a dream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` can't be assigned to. For what you want, you must either:

- Return a new instance from the method, and reassign it outside the method

```js
class Car {
  constructor(name, year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;
  }

  renew() {
    return new Car('Ferrari', 2021);
  }
}

let car = new Car('Ford', 206)
car = car.renew()
console.log(car.year);
```

- Or mutate the instance inside the method

```js
class Car {
  constructor(name, year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;
  }

  renew() {
    Object.assign(this, new Car('Ferrari', 2021));
  }
}

let car = new Car('Ford', 206)
car.renew()
console.log(car.year);
```

Comment: Maybe even `this.constructor('Ferrari', 2021)` - oh, wait, that works only in ES5 but not with `class` :-/

Comment: This is correct, but not this. :-(

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to do this. `this` is immutable. Your options would either be to modify the properties of the class, or create a new class instance and assign it to a your variable in enclosing scope.

I'm also not sure what language you are using that allows assignment to a `this` reference. It's not possible in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979623/why-is-assignment-to-this-not-allowed-in-java), C#, Scala, or Ruby. It's technically possible in Python, but doesn't have the semantics you describe (e.g. it does not mutate the object). You can't even do it in [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476879/how-can-you-assign-a-value-to-the-pointer-this-in-c).